# Meteor local environment variables in development

Tags: meteor, environment-variables

I would like to know the best practice for setting environment variables in local machine to reflect the production environment.

I want to set the private API keys in the ENV variable, rather than directly committing them in Git. In Rails, I would use plugins like [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to put every ENV variables in a single YML file, and they will be available.

What is the common practice in Meteor?

I think I could

1. run `SECRET_KEY=some_key OTHER_SECRET_KEY=some_other_key meteor` every time I run the local server. But that's too much to remember.
2. set environment variables locally but I don't want them to live in the global namespace in my machine.

Any alternatives?

Comment: Go with solution 1 and just copy the command in a `launch.sh` ?

Answer (score 0):

Found this old post while having the same problem.

Looks like meteor is offering now to start with a config file.

```
meteor run --settings config.json
```

You would exclude that (or rather gitignore it) to keep it local. [More here in the docs.](https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#METEOR-SETTINGS)